# ErrorsSetting up timezone tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, timezone

I tried to set the timezone tables in the MySql database locally and I'm not being able to do it.

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysqldb
```

The output of the command was the following ones:

```
Enter password: Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/+VERSION' as time zone. Skipping it.

ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'mysqldb.time_zone' doesn't exist
user:folser user$
```

Do you know what may be happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The name of the database containing the time zone tables is `mysql`, not `mysqldb`.

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also import TimeZone data to your mysql Database using below command :

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < D:/file_path/timezone_2020b_posix_sql/timezone_posix.sql
```

Download [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html)